# Dynamic sum range based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having a hard time figuring out how to make a dynamic range based on a text criteria.
I have the following data:
[image: datasample]

I need to sum the range between the two instances of `Faktura` in the first column `Beskrivelse` while including the first `Faktura` and at the same time I need the range to be limited up to a given end date for an example 31/3/2023. When the sum is done I need to move down to the sum between the next two instances of `Faktura`

I have plus `5000` rows and counting and I need to find out how many payments there are left.

Anyone input would be much appreciated.

I have tried to zero in on the range by using the `FIND` function with a boolean logic.
The same goes for the date range of which the sum should be done.
I need to find out how to move on to the next instance of the sumrange

Comment: Please edit your post to show what you have tried and where you have run into problems. Also, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) and include copyable text in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is using helper column and then adding a formula.

Assume Beskrivelse is in "B" column and Belob is in "D" column.

1. Filter "B" that contains "Faktura".  Then you will see B2 (FakturaSFV35989), B27(FakturaSFV35989) etc.
2. In filtered table write in cell A2; =B2; and fill it down.
3. Clear filters and filter blanks in A column. The first blank should be A3 cell. Write in A3; =A2, then fill it down.
4. Froze the functions.

Then look at the screenshot and change the formulas and design for your need(Fill down all the formulas).
Screenshot:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhYjn.jpg)